Analyzing quality of a response to a question
I have been experimenting with letting an LLM (ChatGPT 4.0) analyze question-response pairs and assess how well the response answers the question and then suggest improvements to the response. It works surprisingly well. Are there any research groups looking at this? I find papers on analysis of how persuasive an argument is, which is related but not the same.


Are there any research groups looking at this?

Yes e.g. https://aclanthology.org/2023.findings-emnlp.123/:

